# Cant save forms to models django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

i cant save my forms to a models into my database the code work smoothly no errors but if  i check in django admin its not save to my database model can you help me 
 here my code :

forms.py

```
class InstagramUsernameForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model = InstagramUsername
       fields = ('nama_orang','username','nama_depan')

   nama_orang = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
   username = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Instagram.objects.values_list("username", flat=True))
   nama_depan = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Instagram.objects.values_list("nama_depan", flat=True))
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Instagram(models.Model):
    nama_depan      =  models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    nama_belakang   =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username        =  models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class InstagramUsername(models.Model):
    nama_orang = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nama_depan = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nama_orang
```

views.py

```
def create2(request):
    akun_form = InstagramUsernameForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if akun_form.is_valid():
            akun_form.save()
        return redirect('sosmed:awe')
    else:
        print(akun_form.errors)
    context = {
        "akun_form":akun_form,
    }

    return render(request,"sosmed/awe.html",context)
```

awe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>awe</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<h1>awe</h1>
<table>
{{ akun_form.as_table }}
</table>
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

cant save forms to django models

Answer (score 1):

values_list returns a list of tuples, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.
so  use *.all()* method instead of *values_list()*

```
 username = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Instagram.objects.all())
```

Comment: if i use objects.all i there 2 value list that i want get is "username" and "nama_depan" i only get this "def __str__(self):
        return self.username" the dropdown will show username instead "nama_depan"